# Cannot get interface speed with standard MIB, use highperf mib (-g)

Tags: monitoring, snmp

Every hour, my team is receiving an email with the following text :

```
Shinken Notification

Notification Type: PROBLEM

Service: NetworkUsage
Host: Monitor
Address: localhost
State: UNKNOWN

Date/Time: 27-09-2016 Additional Info : Cannot get interface speed with standard MIB, use highperf mib (-g) : UNKNOWN
```

I think I found the server that has the problem (it's the monitoring server, since the address is `localhost`), but I can't figure out what to do (I'm a developer and know almost nothing about shinken, nagios or SNMP).

I think I'm missing a MIB that should be able to provide some kind of `highperf` function that would be able.

This is a very old server I don't know where to find / how to install this MIB.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
```

How can I provide this method? Alternatively, how can I disable this particular check for this particular host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to deal with MIB. The message you get means that your interface in question uses 64-bit counters, and those are not enabled by default in check_snmp_int.pl or check_netint.pl.

As the error message suggests, you should add '-g -2' to check_snmp_int.pl command line definition under commands.cfg.

Comment: I found the file, I have this inside : `command_line  $PLUGINSDIR$/check_netint.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C $_HOSTSNMPCOMMUNITY$ -n "$_HOSTNET_IFACES$" -g -2c -f -e -w $_HOSTNET_WARN$ -c $_HOSTNET_CRIT$ -q -k -y -M -B -m -P "$SERVICEPERFDATA$" -T "$LASTSERVICECHECK$"  -o $_HOSTSNMP_MSG_MAX_SIZE$`. So `-g` is there, but not `-2` (or maybe -2c works also ?) I'm going to look for check_netint.pl to see if the options are explained somewhere

Comment: I tried changing `-2c` with `-2`, we'll see if it works in 40 minutes :) Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Still doesn't work :( I'm banging my head on the wall on this one…

Comment: Are you sure you have only one command instance of `check_netint.pl` or `check_snmp_int.pl` in your configuration? There should be another one without -g, as the code implies this to be absent for the error message you mention: `       if (! defined($o_highperf) && (defined($o_prct) || defined ($o_perfs) || defined ($o_perfp))) {
          print "Cannot get interface speed with standard MIB, use highperf mib (-g) : UNKNOWN\n";
   exit $ERRORS{"UNKNOWN"}
  }`

Comment: I looked again, and I think I might have changed something on the wrong monitoring server… it works now! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: In my case `-g -2` reports an error message. According to check_snmp_int.pl help, `-g` or `--64bits`