# How to get ethernet bandwidth statistics with check_snmp?

Tags: nagios, snmp

while running check_snmp_int.pl to get interface names i get the answer

```
# ./check_snmp_int.pl -H 56.22.17.43 -2 -C public  -p 44200  -v  -n zzz
Alarm at 15 + 5
SNMP v2c login
Filter : zzz
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1, Desc : lo
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2, Desc : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
ERROR : Unknown interface zzz
```

but when i use it to query bandwidth usage as mentioned [here](http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_int.html) and also tried to set timeout to 60 secs i get below error

```
# ./check_snmp_int.pl -H 56.22.17.43 -2 -C public  -p 44200 -n "VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller" -k -w 200,400 -c 0,600 -g  -t 60 -v
Alarm at 15 + 5
SNMP v2c login
Filter : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1, Desc : lo
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2, Desc : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
Name : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller, Index : 2
```

Without the "-g" flag i get

```
# ./check_snmp_int.pl -H 56.22.17.43 -2 -C public  -p 44200 -n "VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller" -k -w 200,400 -c 0,600 -v
Alarm at 15 + 5
SNMP v2c login
Filter : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1, Desc : lo
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2, Desc : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
Name : VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller, Index : 2
File read returns : 0 with 6 rows
Cannot get interface speed using highperf mib : UNKNOWN
```

Comment: can you try adding -g -2 per this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/805616/cannot-get-interface-speed-with-standard-mib-use-highperf-mib-g

Comment: @uSlackr i have already tried it if you see the post